# Load DataTable data through button Click

Tags: ajax, datatable, populate

I want to populate DataTable through a button click. Initially the dataTable should be empty:

```
var searchText = $("#textBox").val();

    Table = $("#customerTable").dataTable({
        data:[],
        "columns": [
                    {"data": "Id"   },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "City" },
                    { "data": "Country" }
        ]        
        //"serverSide": true
    });
```

and the button click :

```
$("#SearchButton").on("click", function (event) {

$.ajax({
            url: "/LoadCustomers",
            type: "post"
        });
Table.rows.add(result).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solved !!!

My table looks like this :

```
Table = $("#customerTable").DataTable({
    data:[],
    columns: [
                { "data": "CompanyId"  },
                { "data": "CompanyName" },
                { "data": "City" },
                { "data": "Country" }
    ],
    rowCallback: function (row, data) {},
    filter: false,
    info: false,
    ordering: false,
    processing: true,
    retrieve: true        
});
```

Button Click handler:

```
$("#customerSearchButton").on("click", function (event) {
   $.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "post",
            data: { searchText: searchText }
        }).done(function (result) {
            Table.clear().draw();
            Table.rows.add(result).draw();
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                  // needs to implement if it fails
            });
}
```

Comment: Table is undefined is showing under the Ajax response

Comment: @CyberAbhay define on the top of javascript code
var Table;

Comment: I User version 1.10.20 and throw this :ExtJS:197 
        
       Uncaught TypeError: myDataTable.clear is not a function
    at Object.success (ExtJS:197)
    at c (VM15 jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM15 jquery.min.js:2)
    at l (VM15 jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM15 jquery.min.js:2)